# Please critique the way I write my question on SO

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I posted this question two days ago and it seems that there are not many views.

[Why is req.user (Passport.js) undefined in my MERN app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843680/req-user-passport-js-is-undefined-dont-know-where-is-the-problem)

I am not very familiar with asking questions on SO. Before I posted that question I had already read the official guideline of SO about how to ask good questions. I wonder if my question is too long.

Comment: This seems *huge* in every regard. It takes about 30 LOC just to demonstrate that you log whether `req.user` is defined. As far as I can tell, none of the code shown can be the *cause* of the issue, so people would have to sift through the *two huge* repositories linked. And as far as I understand (not an SME) it might not even be a code problem but a configuration problem.

Comment: Hi MisterMiyagi, thanks for your comments, do you have any suggestions on making it better or smaller? Also, I would love to learn how you deduce it is not the code problem. I am still stuck at that problem.

Comment: @ufo - Recreate the problem with minimal amount of code required to do so, you have also received plenty of feedback which you haven’t addressed

Comment: @SecurityHound One problem I have is I don't know what is the minimal amount of code, do you mean deleting the console.log or do you think some blocks of codes are just irrelevant to the problem? It is hard for me to tell which is truly irrelevant when I don't have a clear idea of the root cause of the issue. 

So pardon me that I don't see the feedbacks I haven't addressed, haven't I answered all the inputs from others?

Comment: First: Can I *copy and paste* the code that you show in the question to the appropriate places; run it without changing anything, and *directly* see the *exact* problem that you describe? If not, make sure to take away *everything that is not directly necessary* to those goals, and add *everything that is directly necessary* to those goals.

Comment: " I don't know what is the minimal amount of code, do you mean deleting the console.log or do you think some blocks of codes are just irrelevant to the problem? It is hard for me to tell which is truly irrelevant when I don't have a clear idea of the root cause of the issue" The things that are relevant are whatever has to be there in order to cause the problem. Everything else is not relevant. If you don't know, then **try it** - if you remove such and such a part, **does the problem still occur?**. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.